# Mouseenter / Mouseleave Simplifying jQuery

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave, simplify

I am building a website for a company promotion and there are 24 map shape "hot spots" on the page that open 24 separate divs. Not my design, but I'm not high enough up to argue my case, so I am going with it. The code that was written by a co-worker is hideous (at least I think so) ---

```
$(".hover1").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".winner1").fadeIn();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(".winner1").stop().fadeOut();
});
```

(x24)

For all 24 different "hot spots" and divs. So you can imagine that each one change to ".hover2", ".hover3", etc... And the same with ".winner2", ".winner3", etc...

This code is around 120 lines.

My question, as I am not a jQuery expert by a long shot, is how to simplify this? I know there has to be a way, I just do not know it.

Each div and hot spot are labeled as such -- "hover1" / "winner1" , "hover2" / "winner2" , etc -- and are connected that way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advanced!!

:-)

**EDIT**

Here is the HTML

For the map

```
<map name="Map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="6,1,258,232" class="hover1"/>
</map>
```

So when you hover over that, this shows up

```
<div class="winner1 badge male">
    <div class="winnerText">
        <p><span>Winner:</span> Clay Cauley</p>
        <p><span>Date:</span> December 3<sup>rd</sup>, 2012</p>
        <p><span>Prize:</span> XBOX 360</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any chance you'll be allowed to write a loop?

Comment: Can you post the HTML. You should be ale to traverse from a `hover` element to `winner` element, or if not you should be able to use a `data` attribute to specify the relevant element to amend

Comment: Does the site really use _strictly unique classes_???

Comment: @JanDvorak -- Anything that helps I can try. And not on every page, this is a special case and that is the easiest way to keep track of all this ... well .. crap.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, I will edit the question to show the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can amend the HTML, try this:

```
<map name="Map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="6,1,258,232" class="hover" data-target="winner1" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="2,2,2,2" class="hover" data-target="winner2" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="3,3,3,3" class="hover" data-target="winner3" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="4,4,4,4" class="hover" data-target="winner4" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="5,5,5,5" class="hover" data-target="winner5" />
</map>
```

```js
$(".hover").hover(function() {
    $("." + $(this).data("target")).fadeIn();
},
function() {
    $("." + $(this).data("target")).stop().fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Deleted my answer because this is a better version of what I was doing. Best answer IMHO.

Comment: @JanDvorak the OP has edited his answer to add the HTML, and he doesn't state that it can't be changed

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks! Talked it over with my boss and showed him this method ... since all I am really doing is adding the `data-target` he's fine with the change. Many thanks!

Comment: @Clay_Cauley no problem, ask your boss to send me the cheque in the post :D

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Already on its way! You should have a very good Holiday season :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of unique classes for .hover and .winner, do the markup something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="hover">
        Hovercontent #1
    </div>

    <div class="winner">
        Winnercontent #1
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="hover">
        Hovercontent #2
    </div>

    <div class="winner">
        Winnercontent #2
    </div>
</div>
```

And then write your javascript something like this.

```
$('.hover').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).siblings('.winner').fadeIn();
}.on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).siblings('.winner').stop().fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could attach the mousenter and mouseleave events to all of your hotspots, and determine which div should be shown/hidden in your function.  This assumes that when you say they are "labeled", you mean that is the id, or some other HTML attribute. Something like -

```
$("map").mouseenter(function(event){
    var index = [some function to find the index of the event.target]; // For example, the index of "hover1" is 1
    $("winner" + index).fadeIn();
}).mouseleave(function(event){
   var index = [some function to find the index of the event.target];
   $("winner" + index).stop().fadeOut();
})
```

Javascript string parsing functions should be easy to find to accomplish parsing the index out of an id, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

If changing the HTML is not possible, and the classes form a sequence, you could still attach the handlers in a loop. Remember to capture the value of the iteration variable (or the concatenated string `".winner"+i`) for the handlers:

```
for(i=1;i<=24;i++){
  (function(i){
    $(".hover"+i).mouseenter(function(){
      $(".winner"+i).fadeIn();
    }).mouseleave(function(){
      $(".winner"+i).stop().fadeOut();
    });
  }(i);
};
```